# Адекватность как норма жизни

Tags: лексика

Идеал современного человека - креативный, коммуникабельный, адекватный. Творческие наклонности и умение работать в коллективе - это понятно, но почему адекватный?

Где-то до 1980 года адекватных людей вообще не было. Встречались адекватные формы,способы, ответы, образы. Или вот у Мандельштама: "Урок творчества Анненского для русской поэзии ― не эллинизация, а внутренний эллинизм, адекватный дух русского языка, так сказать, домашний эллинизм".

Адекватные люди стали появляться после 1990 года, и к 2010 году их количество увеличилось в разы. Что же случилось? У термина появилось новое значение: адекватный - это нормальный?  Или число не слишком нормальных людей значительно возросло?

И вообще, адекватный - это однозначно "хороший, правильный"? А вдруг это "обыкновенный, посредственный, ничем не выделяющийся"? Вот гения уж точно не назовешь адекватным.

А как вы понимаете адекватность как свойство человеческой личности и пользуетесь ли вообще этим термином?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адекватный - это не нормальный, это что-то вроде *комильфо* XIX века, но действует не только на высшее общество, а на любую социальную группу вообще. То есть адекватным можно назвать того, чья внешность и манеры соответствуют данной обстановке.

Причины по которым слово появилось - это изменение в жизни общества в постсоветский период, когда внешние и поведенческие признаки, для определения сословия человека, стали играть более важную роль. Кстати, гения ведущего себя сообразно обстоятельствам вполне могут назвать "адекватом".

Comment: Комильфо – это то, что отвечает правилам хорошего тона:  приличное поведение, дресс-код в одежде. Но мне кажется, что слово "адекватность" в таком значении не используется. Вот реальные примеры: А) Сейчас ребенок очень болезненный, нервный, не всегда адекватный. Б) Если она адекватный человек, то поймет. В) У меня был нормальный инструктор, адекватный.  Он вполне адекватный, журналист грамотный. Г) Я  рад тому, что рядом со мной нормальный, адекватный человек. Мы тоже думали, вроде нормальный парень, совершенно адекватный, и вдруг такой задвиг.

Comment: Комильфо - это сообразный высшему обществу. Адекватный - это сообразный кругу общения. Ваши примеры:

А) Ребёнок не соответствует нормам поведения ребёнка в семье

Б)Если она сообразна нормам поведения - поймёт

В)Инструктор сообразен норме поведения инструктора, а журналист круга говорящего.

Г) Тут вообще подчёркивается, что нормальный и адекватный не совсем одно и тоже. Нормальный - такой как все, адекватный - соответствующий нормам поведения. Человек может быть как не совсем нормальным, но адекватным (А.А. Вассерман), так и не совсем адекватным, но в принципе нормальным (В.В. Жириновский)

Answer (score 2):

Да, адекватный – это нормальный. Дело в том, что жизнь коренным образом изменилась. Нам не интересно, какие душевные качества у нашего коллеги, партнёра по бизнесу, начальника или подчиненного. А что интересно? А вот что: не кинет? Не запросит мильён за копеечную работу? Не подставит? – О, адекватный! То, что нужно.

Но никто не назовет адекватными свою жену, мужа, мать, отца, ребёнка...

Comment: Спасибо, интересное мнение.

Answer (score 2):

Адекватный человек в современном понимании - человек способный адекватно(sic!) воспринимать действительность, адекватный внешнему миру, или представлениям говорящего о нем, способный на адекватные ситуации поступки.

В принципе - обычное стяжение, обычное дело для языка. Но, к сожалению, стало расхожим штампом, особенно в отрицательной форме.

Comment: Может быть, здесь действует такое понятие, как ожидаемость соответствия. Мы ожидаем правильной реакции: люди должны вести себя прилично, на вежливый вопрос мы рассчитываем получить такой же ответ, а учителя, врачи, журналисты должны обладать профессиональными знаниями, если они так себя называют. Всё это можно обозначить как алгоритмы поведения. Получается, что раньше человек был более предсказуемым, а теперь адекватность отмечается особо. Что случилось с обществом, люди стали свободнее, не хотят жить по правилам?

Comment: >> Что случилось с обществом, люди стали свободнее, не хотят жить по правилам?

Точнее, правила все больше и больше размываются. Стираются границы между допустимым и недопустимым, между добром и злом, нормой и патологией и т.д. А это значит, что нормы нет.

Comment: А как обозначить и оценить это явление? Это деградация общества или временный кризис переходного периода?

Comment: Всё только к лучшему. Если жизнь вокруг нас становится всё менее и менее адекватной, значит - мы стареем!

Comment: Не исключено. Но почему, к примеру, до 1990 года эту мысль если и высказывали, то  другими словами. Или всё человечество постарело?

Comment: Именно, что другими словами. С 1990 года всё человечество постарело на четверть века. Пришло новое поколение, со своими словечками и своими представлениями о нормальности и адекватности. Пройдет время, и нынешняя молодежь скажет: "Куда мир катится? Вот раньше такого безобразия не было."

Comment: >Что случилось с обществом, люди стали свободнее, не хотят жить по правилам? 
 
Не здесь об этом рассуждать. Одно могу сказать: прямой связи между адекватностью, нормальностью и предсказуемостью я не вижу ни для какой пары. Некоторая косвенная, корреляционная - возможно. Но в целом - нет.

Comment: А почему вы ее не видите? Вот к примеру, если Вы нечаянно коснетесь очень горячей поверхности, то  отдернете руку - такая реакция АДЕКВАТНАЯ и поэтому ПРЕДСКАЗУЕМАЯ. Но это, если Вы  НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ человек, а не йог какой-нибудь. Мне кажется, адекватность - это одна из составляющих нормальности, то есть более узкое понятие.

Comment: >> А как обозначить и оценить это явление? Это деградация общества или временный кризис переходного периода?

У-у... Я, как пессимист, оцениваю как деградацию. Если норма исчезает – это страшно.

Comment: >А почему вы ее не видите? 

Это условный рефлекс. Если не безусловный. Адекватность в рассматриваемом понимании начинается с рассудочной деятельности. Так что - неудачный пример. Хотя, даже без этого ваш пример логически не оправдан. Одергивание руки - это избыточно, отнюдь не "адекватно". Дарвин (кажется) отшатнулся от змеи за прочнейшим стеклом. Какая уж тут "адеватность". Но это тоже не самое главное. Главное, что "предсказуемость" связана не с адекватностью, а с опытом наблюдателя.

Answer (score 2):

Словом "адекватный" не пользуюсь, как и всеми остальными, по возможности, пластиковыми, синтетическими, кислотными заимствованиями, которые не передают в русской речи глубинных смыслов, свойственных русским/славянским словам. "Адекватный"(изначально медицинский термин.) - это всего-навсего "соответствующий" ("тождественный"), и при этом соответствующий самому говорящему. Не раз замечал, что "адекватный человек" в оценке подонка и сам оказывается подонком. Это строго субъективное определение, и ошибочно его пытаться привязать к объективным характеристикам. "Адекватный" не свидетельствует ни о чем, кроме личного мнения говорящего, его собственной проекции на субъект. Как почти все современные американизмы (хотя это - не американизм), такое слово выхолащивает настоящее описание: это (или он) что - "равный", "равноценный", "совпадающий"? Да нет. В отличие от русских слов "адекватный" - какой-то аморфный, может он/это - "хороший"?, "правильный"?, может "порядочный"?, или "умный"?, "сметливый"?, а вот - "добрый"? Да нет же - не то и не другое. А это - "никакой" с позитивным оттенком. Как и другие американизмы - НИКАКОЙ ответственности, прямоты и честности. Особенно слово из фотодела "позитивный"/"негативный" - пик лексического лицемерия. Кто такой "позитивный"? Это добрый, светлый, жизнерадостный, хороший, порядочный, честный, радушный, добродушный (и ещё 15 синонимов, убитых этим американизмом)? Нет, ничего из это в отдельности. Благодаря этому красивейшему американизму (спасибо им не только за смартфоны) "пизитивный" убито столько важных русских слов с корнем "добро" и "благо", он ТАК обогатил речь русских людей. Теперь можно сказать: "он хоть и дерьмо, но позитивное", а "она - немного негативная прелестница". Теперь можно сказать "это президент немного более "легитимен", чем тот". Красота! Как раньше было неудобно, ведь по-русски невозможно сказать: "быть чуть менее (или чуть более) законным" (Это как "беременным".) Красота! "Нет, он не вор, он порядочный "коррупционер"". "Хочу устроиться на работу "киллером" или "путаной"". Вот они Ваши стремления к "обогащению" русского языка. А ведь "Сначала было слово..." Язык - это душа народа, его главный образующий элемент. Не было бы украинского языка - и на Украине сейчас  не лилась бы кровь одного и того же народа. Российские русисты легкомысленно (а по сути - невежественно) считают, что "с языком ничего не случится", "пусть обогащается" словами с пустыми или ложными смыслами. Но другие лингвисты почему-то поставили барьеры от заимствований, зачем-то занимаются словообразованием неологизмов на основе родных корней. Может они идиоты? Ну ведь правда, у арабистов нет такой проблемы, как осознать значение слова "адекватный". Вместо этого у них свои слова "муляим" или "мунасиб". А смыслы их знают даже трехлетние дети. Тут и диссертаций не напишешь! Нет, все-таки наши русисты молодцы, хорошо устроились. Язык за них формирует народ (правда в лице нескольких тысяч полуграмотных кривативов), им остаётся только наблюдать, как за бабочками или рыбками в аквариуме. А сколько потом материала для рассуждизмов, о придании новых оттенков и значений, для составления словарей иностранных слов, кто быстрей. Наши лингвисты - самые практичные лингвисты в мире! ("Практичный" - это слово иностранное, всем не понять, означает "лицемерный", "подлый", "предательский")

Answer (score 0):

Соответствующий, отвечающий требованием.
Как фрик пользуюсь этим словом. Причём для меня сие понятие означает именно то, чем является в английском. Два синонима, которые я привела - это и есть "адекватный". Употребляю в речи. Не сталкивалась с непониманием. Сложность понятия такова: на разных уровнях общества (и в разных обществах же) адекватность может быть разнообразной. Нормы поведения, сознательность, чуткость и степень, простите, трезвости ума: в каждом слое общества к ним свои требования и запросы.
То есть адекватным "совсем" быть невозможно, можно только кому-то... каким-то нормам, чьим - уже отдельный вопрос...